# Return tkinter listbox result to main script

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am new to tkinter/python and I fear my question is so simple, no one was dumbed it down to this point. I have created the following script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class example(tk.Frame):

    #Initialize class
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self,selectmode=SINGLE)
        self.listbox.pack(expand=True)
        self.button = tk.Button(self,text="Confirm Selection",command=self.selection)
        self.button.pack(side="bottom",fill="both",expand=True)
        self.string = tk.StringVar()

        #Add variables
        for i in ['A','B','C']:
            self.listbox.insert(END,i)

    #Selection method
    def selection(self):
        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
        name = ['A','B','C'][index]
        self.string = name
        print(self.string)

#Main script
root = tk.Tk()
example(root).pack(expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

I am able to print the result of my list selection within

```
def selection(self)
```

However, I do not know how to pull out and use further as the script continues to run. For example, if my #Main script were to be continued, I would like to do something like:

```
letter = '''results of listbox selection'''
```

As a bonus, I am having difficulty destroying the listbox, with only the list and the button being removed for the methods I have tried.

Thanks everyone

Comment: The result of the selection is in the variable `self.string`. You can use it anywhere in the class. If you want to use the selection value after the main loop terminates, use a global variable instead of an instance variable.

Comment: What methods have you tried to destroy the listbox?

Comment: I have tried the `self.listbox.destroy()` and `self.button.destroy()` but the window does not close, and my script stops running at that point

Comment: I sorted out the destroy, but my code still doesn't resume once the listbox is "destroyed"

Comment: I can help you out if you can provide a little more information about what you intend the script to do. So far I’m not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish and I am also getting an error from your index.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. I was unaware of how to properly use the `wait_window` function to resume the script once a value is returned.

I have modified substantially and the below fits my purposes:

```
from tkinter import *

class ListBoxChoice(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None, title=None, message=None, list=[]):
        self.master = master
        self.value = None
        self.list = list[:]
        
        self.modalPane = Toplevel(self.master)

        self.modalPane.transient(self.master)
        self.modalPane.grab_set()

        self.modalPane.bind("<Return>", self._choose)
        self.modalPane.bind("<Escape>", self._cancel)

        if title:
            self.modalPane.title(title)

        if message:
            Label(self.modalPane, text=message).pack(padx=1, pady=1)

        listFrame = Frame(self.modalPane)
        listFrame.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        scrollBar = Scrollbar(listFrame)
        scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.listBox = Listbox(listFrame, selectmode=SINGLE)
        self.listBox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        scrollBar.config(command=self.listBox.yview)
        self.listBox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
        self.list.sort()
        for item in self.list:
            self.listBox.insert(END, item)

        buttonFrame = Frame(self.modalPane)
        buttonFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        chooseButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="Choose", command=self._choose)
        chooseButton.pack()

        cancelButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="Cancel", command=self._cancel)
        cancelButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def _choose(self, event=None):
        try:
            firstIndex = self.listBox.curselection()[0]
            self.value = self.list[int(firstIndex)]
        except IndexError:
            self.value = None
        self.modalPane.destroy()

    def _cancel(self, event=None):
        self.modalPane.destroy()
        
    def returnValue(self):
        self.master.wait_window(self.modalPane)
        return self.value
        self.modalPane.destroy()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    list = ['A','B','C']

    returnValue = ListBoxChoice(root, "Pick Letter", "Pick one of these crazy random numbers", list).returnValue()
    print(returnValue)'
```

The only issue I have now is am I getting 2 dialog boxes open when I run the script. I'm sure it has something to do with how I am binding everything, but still sorting.